# Exchange 2013 Setup "You have tried to create a channel to a service that does not support .Net Framing"

Tags: exchange

I am receiving the following error when trying to setup Microsoft Exchange 2013 on a new server.

I have followed all of the instructions noted in Microsoft's guide:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/14506.how-to-install-exchange-2013-on-windows-server-2012.aspx

However when I run the installer it throws this error when setting up the "Mailbox role: Transport service."

Any insight on this would be greatly appreciated.

```
Error:
The following error was generated when "$error.Clear(); 
            if ($RoleProductPlatform -eq "amd64")
            {
                $useAttachMode = $false;
                $fastInstallConfigPath = Join-Path -Path $RoleBinPath -ChildPath "Search\Ceres\Installer";
                $command = Join-Path -Path $fastInstallConfigPath -ChildPath "InstallConfig.ps1";
                $fastDefaultDataFolderPath = Join-Path -Path $RoleBinPath -ChildPath "Search\Ceres\HostController\Data";
                $dataFolderPath = $fastDefaultDataFolderPath;

                if ([System.IO.Directory]::Exists($fastDefaultDataFolderPath))
                {
                    $useAttachMode = $true;
                }
                else
                {
                    if ($RoleIsDatacenter -eq $true)
                    {
                        $preferredDataFolderPathRoot = "D:\";
                        if ([System.IO.Directory]::Exists($preferredDataFolderPathRoot))
                        {
                            $dataFolderPath = Join-Path -Path $preferredDataFolderPathRoot -ChildPath "ExchangeSearchData";
                            if ([System.IO.Directory]::Exists($dataFolderPath))
                            {
                                $useAttachMode = $true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                if ($useAttachMode -eq $true)
                {
                    &$command -action a -dataFolder $dataFolderPath -silent;
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {   
                        &$command -action i -dataFolder $dataFolderPath -silent;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        $errorMsg = "Failure running SearchFoundation installconfig.ps1 - " + $_.Exception.Message;
                        Write-ExchangeSetupLog -Error $errorMsg;
                        &$command -action u -silent;
                        try
                        {
                            if ([System.IO.Directory]::Exists($dataFolderPath))
                            {
                                [System.IO.Directory]::Delete($dataFolderPath, $true);
                            }
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            $deleteErrorMsg = "Failure cleaning up SearchFoundation Data folder. - " + $dataFolderPath + " - " + $_.Exception.Message;
                            Write-ExchangeSetupLog -Error $deleteErrorMsg;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        " was run: "Failure running SearchFoundation installconfig.ps1 - Error occurred while configuring Search Foundation for Exchange.System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: You have tried to create a channel to a service that does not support .Net Framing.  ---> System.IO.InvalidDataException: Expected record type 'PreambleAck', found '46'.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.FramingDecoder.ValidatePreambleAck(FramingRecordType foundType)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientDuplexDecoder.Decode(Byte[] bytes, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionUpgradeHelper.ValidateUpgradeResponse(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, ClientFramingDecoder decoder)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionUpgradeHelper.InitiateUpgrade(StreamUpgradeInitiator upgradeInitiator, IConnection& connection, ClientFramingDecoder decoder, IDefaultCommunicationTimeouts defaultTimeouts, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.SendPreamble(IConnection connection, ArraySegment`1 preamble, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.DuplexConnectionPoolHelper.AcceptPooledConnection(IConnection connection, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnection(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EnsureOpened(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.Ceres.HostController.WcfTypes.IHostController.GetHostInformation()
   at Microsoft.Ceres.Exchange.PostSetup.HostControllerManager.ConnectHost(Uri uri, Boolean secure, String userIdentity, Int16 timeoutInSeconds)
   at Microsoft.Ceres.Exchange.PostSetup.DeploymentManager.DeployAdminNode(String installDirectory, String localHostControllerNetTcpUrl, Int32 hostControllerPort)
   at Microsoft.Ceres.Exchange.PostSetup.DeploymentManager.Install(String installDirectory, String dataDirectoryPath, Int32 basePort, String logFile, Boolean singleNode, String systemName, Boolean attachedMode)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Type , Object , Object , Object , Object , Object , Object , Boolean )".
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly which build of Exchange 2013 are you trying to install?

For a fresh installation it should be CU16, with Net Framework 4.6.2 installed.

If you had installed that version of Net Framework and are trying to install something older than CU15 then you will be getting errors.

All Exchange CUs are the complete product, so you can do a fresh install using them - there is no need to install something older and then update.

Comment: You know, it didn't actually say. I just downloaded it from Microsoft's evalcenter Website. https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/evalcenter/evaluate-exchange-server-2013. I am re downloading CU16.

Comment: If you can work out which version the eval centre is letting you download (I don't really want to download it to check) and it isn't CU16, let me know and I will get it looked at (Exchange MVP).

Comment: I extracted the package, the setup program says its version 15.00.0516.027 pic attached http://i.imgur.com/fYSOG0A.png

Comment: That is RTM. I will get it flagged.